# Taylor series for $|y|^x(2-y)=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, taylor-expansion, roots, inverse-function

Knowking that
$$|y|^x(2-y)=1$$
for $y\neq1$;

How can one discover a series expression for $y$? That is, how can one discover a series expression for the root of the characteristic polynomial of a x-bonacci sequence?

One thing to note is:
$$x=-\log_{|y|}(2-y)$$

Comment: Try looking for other questions solving $x^r+ax+b=0$